# NSUserDefaults not incrementing

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsinteger

I am trying to increase an `NSInteger` using `NSUserDefaults` like this:

```
NSInteger attempts = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"tries"];
NSInteger newA = attempts++;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:newA forKey:@"tries"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
NSLog(@"Tries: %d",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"tries"]);
```

However this is my `NSLogs`:

```
Tries: 0
Tries: 0
Tries: 0
```

Comment: Have you initiated it?

Comment: On 64-bit systems `NSInteger` may not work with `%d` correctly. Try `NSLog(@"Tries: %d", (int)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"tries"]);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is your issue

```
NSInteger newA = attempts++;
```

You're incrementing attempts after you set it to newA, try this instead :

```
NSInteger newA = ++attempts;
```

Comment: Which why `NSInteger newA = attempts + 1;` is a better way to go, it does not have extra semantics such as pre vs post update. Or even just update `attempts`: `attempts +=1;` and skip `newA`.